# How can I access the results from spring actuator healthcheck in Java code?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

I've setup a healthcheck actuator with the endpoint /actuator/health, which produces something like the following for my application when you go to the URL:

```
{"status":"UP","app":{"status":"UP"},"db":{"status":"UP"}}
```

Is there a way I can access these results in my Java code using the Spring APIs? I'm monitoring for any that go down and sending out slack notifications when they do, I'm particularly interested in monitoring when the DB goes down. I've already got the method that creates the slack notification, I just need the name of the component that has gone down (i.e. db).

Can anyone help with this?

Hopefully my question makes sense, I'm pretty new to this still.

Edit: I've @Override Health, if the whole app goes down it goes into this, not sure if there is a way at this stage to get what else is down at the time (db etc) and pass into the slack method?:

```
    @Override
    public Health health() {
        System.out.println("HealthIndicator called at " + LocalDateTime.now() + " state=" + (state?"Up":"Down"));
        if(state) {
            return Health.up().build();
        } else { 
    triggerSlackNotifications(failedComponent, status);
            return Health.down().build();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get more details of the health status you can add following in your `application.properties`

```
management.endpoint.health.enabled=true
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
```

After that, you will get more information as below.

```
{
    "status": "UP",
    "details": {
        "diskSpace": {
            "status": "UP",
            "details": {
                "total": 467848392704,
                "free": 69999702016,
                "threshold": 10485760
            }
        },
        "db": {
            "status": "UP",
            "details": {
                "database": "MySQL",
                "hello": 1
            }
        },
        "mail": {
            "status": "UP",
            "details": {
                "location": "smtp.gmail.com:<port>"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Solution

```
@GetMapping("/statusDB")
    public String healthCheck() throws IOException, JSONException
    {

          StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
          URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/actuator/health");
          HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
          conn.getResponseCode();
          BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
          String line;
          while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
             result.append(line);
          }
          rd.close();
          System.out.println("Result: "+result.toString());

          JSONObject jsonObject =new JSONObject(result.toString());
          System.out.println("jsonObject: "+jsonObject);

          return "Status of Database is "+jsonObject.getJSONObject("details").getJSONObject("db").get("status");
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need to execute Webendpoint and scrape the response. Better and less error prone way is to use the Actuator Health Beans itself.

e.g.

**Aggregated Status**

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.Status;
@Component
public class MyHealthStatusProvider {
    private final HealthEndpoint healthEndpoint;
    public MyHealthStatusProvider(HealthEndpoint healthEndpoint) {
        this.healthEndpoint = healthEndpoint;
    }
    public Status getHealthStatus() {
        return this.healthEndpoint.health().getStatus();
    }
}
```

**Component Level Status**

```
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicator;

@Component
public class MyComponentHealthStatusProvider {
    private final List<HealthIndicator> healthIndicators;

public MyHealthStatusProvider(List<HealthIndicator> healthIndicators) {
        this.healthIndicators = healthIndicators;
    }

    public List<HealthIndicator> getHealthStatus() {
        return this.healthIndicators;
    }
}
```

That’s it. Now you can very easily call these methods and get the applciation health status.

You can see more info on my post here:
https://saggu.medium.com/how-to-get-spring-actuator-health-status-through-java-code-71864efacc73