# How to get healthcheck status without calling actuator endpoint?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, health-check

In a springboot application I want to produce `/version` endpoint which combines some of `/actuator/health` and `/actuator/info` data.
From health endpoint I need overall status `UP`/`DOWN`.

How can I retrieve **application status** inside java code?

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69365535/10950272) I tried to retrieve all `HealthIndicator` beans:

```java
@RestController
public class AppStatusRestController {
    private final List<HealthIndicator> healthIndicators;

    public AppStatusRestController(List<HealthIndicator> healthIndicators) {
        this.healthIndicators = healthIndicators;
    }

    @GetMapping("/status")
    public String status() {
        return "status: " + getStatus();
    }
    private String getStatus() {
        return isUp() ? Status.UP.getCode() : Status.DOWN.getCode();

    }

    private boolean isUp() {
        return this.healthIndicators.stream().allMatch(healthIndicator -> healthIndicator.getHealth(false).getStatus() == Status.UP);
    }

}
```

but it doesn't work for some components, e.g. RabbitMQ

```json
{
  status: "DOWN", // how can I get application status 
  components: {
    db: {
      status: "UP",
...
    },
    diskSpace: {
      status: "UP",
...
      }
    },
    ping: {
      status: "UP"
    },
    rabbit: {
      status: "DOWN",
      details: {
        error: "org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect"
      }
    },
    myCustomHealthIndicator: {
      status: "UP",
...
    }
  }
}
```

Note that I don't need component status at all. I just want to retrieve overall status of my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63510958/10950272) that `HealthEndpoint` was what I was looking for.

```java
@RestController
public class AppStatusRestController {
    private final HealthEndpoint healthEndpoint;

    public AppStatusRestController(HealthEndpoint healthEndpoint) {
        this.healthEndpoint = healthEndpoint;
    }

    @GetMapping("/status")
    public String status() {
        return "status: " + healthEndpoint.health().getStatus();
    }

}
```